# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize display, sound and other components on HP

Tags: 20.04, sound, display, hp

I'm having issues with this new HP Elitebook 840, G10...
It came with W11 installed and works well. I put an ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot
and all internal components drivers seem to be failing...

Took me a week to make the wifi to work, now for the display and sound still nothing...

Of course I tried to install all ubuntu again but did not help either (also with 18.04 or 22.04...).

Basically,

- display shows as unknown (so no brightness control, etc), and lshw shows it as "UNCLAIMED".
- i have no sound from internal speakers (headphones work though) as output shows "dummy output".

I tried most fix or stuff around the internet without success, like getting latest kernel, updating drivers, modifying grub, blabla... :(

Any help or way to troubleshoot further my problem will be very appreciated.
I can post any output you might need :)

Thanks again!

Comment: The "HP Elitebook 840, G10" is an 2023 device. Installing 20.04 is expected to result in errors. Install 23.10, or since your device was released around fall, you might have to install the beta 24.04

Comment: Mhmh, but according to https://ubuntu.com/certified/202302-31228, it is certified for 22.04 isn't it? I had same problems on 22 ...

Comment: Based on that link, you might need to find and install "the 6.1.0-1009-oem kernel."

Comment: Ah yeah, I see what you mean, it's even specified "Pre-installed in some regions with a custom Ubuntu image that takes advantage of the system’s hardware features and may include additional software. Standard images of Ubuntu may not work well, or at all."
So it might never work...